# Task manager always showing 95% to 100% disk usage

Tags: windows-10

Please tell me a way to solve this problem[image]

Comment: I have tried 
net.exe stop "windows search"  still its showing 95% to 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can try following ways:

1. Update Windows: (`WinKey->Check for Updates`)
2. Change web browser
3. Disable startup items
4. Enable High Performance mode
5. Update Anti-virus

If any of above doesn't work then track manually that where is the disk more utilised.